# Cant pass a variables into a class

Tags: python, class, pyqt, pyqt4

While passing a object "series_lineEdit" in another class i am getting an error

The error:

```
in __init__
    super(Ui_series_search, self).__init__(parent)
TypeError: QWidget(parent: QWidget = None, flags: Qt.WindowFlags = 0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'-------
```

---

The code:

```
class UiMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UiMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        #codes
        self.series_lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        a = UiSeries(self, str(self.series_lineEdit.text()))


class UiSeries(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, series_name, parent = None):
        super(UiSeries, self).__init__(parent)
        self.series_name = series_name
        print(series_name)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: made the edit. and thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You are calling `UiSeries()` with a parent widget and a string.  However, you declared its `__init__`() to take those parameters in the opposite order...

Comment: Thanks for the solution. calling without its main widget sovled the problem.
UiSeries(str(...)) instead of UiSeries(self, str(..))